# Formal scheme as tubular neighbourhoods

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I heard that one can think of the completion of a scheme $X$ along a closed subscheme $Y$ as a tubular neighbourhood of $Y$ in the ambient space $X$.

I can see in the case when $X=\mathbb{A}^2$, and $Y$ is any closed point, the formal completion is isomorphic to $k[[x.y]]$, this 'kind of ' reflect that each point of the plane has similar neighbourhood.

My question is: In what sense is the formal completion 'a neighbourhood' of $Y$ and how can we see it with rigour? (my guess is this has something to do with étale covering)

Comment: It's the colimit (in the appropriate category--locally topologically ringed spaces) of the 'fuzzy neighborhoods' $Y/I_X^n$ which one should think about as adding to $X$ some small fuzz which, in some sense, is a neighborhood since this fuzz is tangency direction.